# Simple Class --> Class property updation

Tags: python, class

I have a simple class. This is the output I got:

```
>>> print(Customer.total_amount)
1300
```

but I expected the output to be:

```
>>> print(Customer.total_amount)
1000
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Customer:
    total_amount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, mob, email, amount=None):
        self.name = name
        self.mob = mob
        self.eamil = email
        self.amount = 0

    def add_amount(self, amount):
        self.amount += amount
        Customer.total_amount += self.amount

cust1 = Customer("cust1", "8892398598", "ritheshb1@gmail.com")
cust2 = Customer("cust2", "8892498598", "ritheshb2@gmail.com")
cust1.add_amount(100)
cust2.add_amount(200)
cust1.add_amount(300)
cust2.add_amount(400)

print(cust1.amount)
print(cust2.amount)
print(Customer.total_amount)
```

Comment: but instance output getting as correct output:     
print(cust1.amount) = 400,
print(cust2.amount) = 600

Comment: So why are you adding `self.amount` (which was just altered on the preceding line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
Customer.total_amount += self.amount
```

to

```
Customer.total_amount += amount
```